Require pin / fingerprint to execute program
In Win10, after already being logged into my account, is there a way to require a password to start a specific app? For example for apps in which I manage finances. I would like the extra step of confirmation as someone else will work on my machine (and yes, my account) from time to time.
Ideally, this would also accept a fingerprint that I've set up for account login.

Use a portable app, and store the application in an encrypted Zip file. To use that application, you or another user would need to enter a password to open the Zip.

If they have access to your account and the app doesn't provide it's own user authentication separate from the windows user account then it's unlikely windows will be able to offer any protection natively.
If you can create another account, you could make one specifically for the apps you want to protect. You, and others can still use the main account but only you can use the special one.
You can either switch user or create a shortcut to 'run as' the special user which would prompt for a password and I think allow you to use biometrics too.
This assumes that the application supports per-user account data storage.

From a security standpoint the correct way is to setup a new account for the second user and no access to the specific apps.
If the second user isn't technical savy, an easy way to reenforce an authentication is to edit the shortcuts on the desktop.
Right-Click the shortcut, Properties and change target.
Original: "C:\Program Files\Finance\secureMe.exe"
Edit: runas /user:[YourAccount] "C:\Program Files\Finance\secureMe.exe"
This will open a console which will ask for the password of the given user.
A smart user will still be able to start the program by directly navigating to the program folder.
If you want to use this with more security focus. Create a second Account which is the only one with access to the specific apps and use runas to start them from your mainaccount.
You still have to check where data is saved, when a program is started like that.
Source from Answers.Microsoft
